# How to add new column to existing dataframe (no headers) using iloc?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create third column to existing dataframe, having the same values of 2nd column using iloc pandas method.
What are the options do I have ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([*zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6])])
```

Comment: Is iloc really the only method you wish to use?

Comment: Also, are you trying to refer all the rows in the 2nd column to make the 3rd column?

Comment: Yes. I want to use iloc method, and refer all the rows in the 2nd column to make the 3rd column.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
df.insert(len(df.columns), # position of new column, it points to column after last column
          len(df.columns), # naming could be the location of column
          value=df.iloc[:,1] # grab the values from last column
         )
df
```

```
    0   1   2
0   1   4   4
1   2   5   5
2   3   6   6
```